# Chrome Extension using Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi I am making a chrome extension using javascript which takes a excel file as input and display the result from the excel file. Is there a way that the same excel file is loaded again when i open the extension again without uploading it again?

Comment: You might want to read up on the [`chorme.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) API (linked)

Answer (score 0):

IndexedDB is your friend! IndexedDB can be used to cache files, images etc. I am pretty sure you can store .excel files too.